# Can we OAuth without overwriting the user's current login?

Tags: oauth, canvas, app

We’re currently working on integrating our application with Salesforce as a canvas app and hit a snag.

Our application uses OAuth to allows a single user to grant our app access to multiple orgs (using OAuth with a different login each time).

However, the user’s current Salesforce login/cookies is overwritten with each new OAuth login. This clearly breaks the Salesforce user experience as the canvas app lives within a Salesforce org and the user is now logged into a different org.

Is there an a solution to this problem? e.g. Can I access the metadata API of an org that isn’t the one that the user is currently using to access our canvas app?

Cheers,
Spencer

Answer (score 0):

I think this post of Jitendra might help you,

https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/use-lightning-components-on-external-websites-lightning-out/

Since it shows how to encapsulate a Lightning Component into an external web-app, it might be the same reasoning if you want to integrate your external sfdc app into another org thorugh canvas.